# C# aspx decimal thousand with comma and decimal with dot

Tags: c#

I would like when I use `ToString` method on `decimal` to get output like:

```
1.234,56
```

now is like:

```
1234,56
```

In `global.asax.cs` i have used:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("sl-SI");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
```

But doesn't work. Is there any global solution for that or how to fix my problem?

Comment: `foo.ToString("N2", culture);`

Comment: Then I need to change code in more then 1000 lines. Is this only solution?

Comment: I prefer being explicit in the ToString() and not changing global state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .net 4.5 you can use `CultureInfo` which allows you to set the default culture for all Threads in the current AppDomain.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=VS.110).aspx

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("sl-SI");

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
```

Comment: Your code is setting the Culture for the current thread only, but if you put this code code in the startup point of your application it will set the default culture for all threads in your application

Comment: I tried but is still the same. Number is like 1234,56 and not like 1.234,56

Comment: For grouping seperator to work to need to do `ToString("N")`

Comment: @Jaske Rote so is not possible to do this in global config?

Comment: @senzacionale not that I know of as `"N"` is a format option and can be different in any situation. But the `NumberGroupSeperator` value will be used when you use `"N"`

Answer (score 0):

Place your code into `Application_BeginRequest` in Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var culture = new CultureInfo("sl-SI");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
}
```

**Correction:**

As per Jake Rote's suggestion, set the default thread culture in the `Application_Start` method in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Code goes here
}
```

Comment: @senzacionale The reason this code would not be working is because ASP.NET uses threads internally so it is quite possible the Thread in `Application_BeginRequest` is not the same one that your controller is called in